# How do I copy a spring boot repackaged jar from a different module when using Gradle and the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-module gradle project that uses the Spring Boot Gradle plugin in which one module builds spring boot repackaged jar, and another module attempts to build a docker container.

How do you copy a spring boot repackaged jar from a different module?

I tried this:

```
task copyBootJar(type: Copy, overwrite: true) {
    from project(':foo-bar:spring-boot-project').jar
    into "${buildDir}/libs"
}

build.dependsOn copyBootJar
```

But unfortunately that only copies the original unrepackaged jar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I was facing was that :foo-bar:spring-boot-project' was not evaluated yet.

I found the answer here:  http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Trouble-accessing-sibling-project-configuration-td3384352.html

The solution was to add the following code to the build.gradle file:

```
    evaluationDependsOn(':foo-bar:spring-boot-project')
```

so that the total solution now looks like this:

```
    evaluationDependsOn(':foo-bar:spring-boot-project')

    task copyBootJar(type: Copy, overwrite: true) {
        from project(':foo-bar:spring-boot-project').jar
        into "${buildDir}/libs"
    }

    build.dependsOn copyBootJar
```